Is the graph of a smooth real-valued strictly monotonic function defined on a countable union of intervals of R a manifold with boundary in RXR?
Specifically, if we denote by $M \subset R$ a set that is a countable union of intervals (closed, half-closed or open) and have a smooth, strictly monotonic function $f: M \rightarrow R$, is it the case that $G \equiv \{(x,f(x)),\; x \in M \}$ is a manifold with boundary in $R^2$? I have looked for existing results, since Lee's ISM proof that  graphs of smooth functions are manifolds does not consider manifolds with boundary (AFAIK).
I believe the answer is yes but would like to know if my thinking is correct (I may be overthinking this): Since $f$ is strictly monotonic its inverse exists and is continuous. Now, for any $(r,f(r)) \in G$ for which $r$ is an interior point of an interval $I \subset M$ there exists an open interval $U = (a,b)$ contained in $I$ and containing $r$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, $V \equiv \{(p,f(p)), p \in (a,b)\})$ is a neighborhood of $(r,f(r))$ in $G$ and it, together with the projection $\pi: (p,f(p)) \rightarrow p$ from $V$ to $(a,b)$ comprise a chart for $G$ at $(r,f(r))$. On the other hand, if $(r,f(r)) \in G$ is such that $r$ is an endpoint of an interval $I \subset M$ (assume without loss of generality $r$ is a right endpoint), then there is an open interval $U = (a,b)$ such that $U \cap M = (a,r]$ is a neighborhood of $r$ in $M$. Again, by the continuity of $f^{-1}$, the set $V \equiv \{(p,f(p)),p \in (a,r])\}$ is a neighborhood of $(r,f(r))$ in $G$ and the map $\pi$ is a homeomorphism of $V$ and $(a,r]$ which takes $(r,f(r))$ onto $r$. To complete the proof we just need to map $(a,r]$ into $[0,r-a)$ via $\phi: p \rightarrow r-p$ to conclude that $(V,\phi \circ \pi)$ is a boundary chart for $G$ at $(r,f(r))$.

The answer is no. Hint: The boundary of a 1-manifold is a 0-manifold, i.e. a discrete space of at most countable cardinality.

OK, thanks for posting, I believe I understand your point, but wouldn't the boundary of the graph of my function be the collection of points which are images, by $f$, of the endpoints of the intervals of $M$, which is countable?

Countable, yes, but I highlighted discrete in my comment for a reason :)

I see, but isn't a discrete space one in which each point has a neighborhood containing only itself? I am willing to work at it, but say we simplify to $M$ being a single half-closed interval, say its right endpoint is $e$. Isn't ${e,f(e)}$ a discrete set, and wouldn't it be the boundary of the graph of $f$? Again, I appreciate your help here.

Perhaps the first useful thing to note is that if you take $f(x) = x$ as your function, then $G$ is homeomorphic to $M$ (in fact this ought to be true for general $f$, but let's stay simple), so it is enough to find an $M$ whose boundary points form a non-discrete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. ...but I see Lee Mosher has beat me to the punchline :)

Here is general fact about an arbitrary continuous function $f : X \to Y$ between an arbitrary pair of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$: the graph $G \equiv \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X\} \subset X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$. For the proof: the function $X \mapsto G$ given by $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ is continuous; and its inverse function $G \mapsto X$ given by $(x,f(x)) \mapsto x$ is (well-defined and) continuous.
Note: you do not need smoothness, nor strict monotonicity, nor non-strict monotonicity of the function $f$. All you need is continuity of $f$.
So your question is equivalent to asking this:

If we denote by $M \subset R$ a set that is a countable union of intervals ... is $M$ a manifold with boundary?

Here is a counterexample:
$$M = [-1,0] \cup \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \, \left[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}\right] \right)
$$
In $M$, the point $0$ is not a manifold interior point because no open interval around $0$ is an open subset of $M$, nor is $0$ a manifold boundary point because no half-open interval with endpoint $0$ is an open subset of $M$.

Where your proof seems to go wrong is right here:

... if $(r,f(r)) \in G$ is such that $r$ is an endpoint of an interval $I \subset M$ (assume without loss of generality $r$ is a right endpoint), then there is an open interval $U = (a,b)$ such that $U \cap M = (a,r]$...

As you can see from my example, there need not exist any $U=(a,b)$ such that $U \cap M = (a,r]$.

So $X$ is a "global chart", in a way. I understand what you (and Ben) are saying, thanks to both of you for taking the time. Believe it or not I had considered this possibility but only thought about simple examples that just amounted to "extending" the closed interval. I don't want to wear out my welcome but if I could ask one more question:  If, for example, $M$ only consisted of a finite number of intervals then my proof would go through?

Yes, because a finite union of subintervals of $R$ is a manifold (proof by induction).

OK, I feel lousy for missing this but not too lousy because I actually understand the explanation. :) Again, I appreciate the time.
